# ATI HD 6620G и Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amd

Не работает Ubuntu 16.04 без NoModeSet. Такое было и на предыдущих версиях, но после установки fglrx всё проходило. На 16.04 fglrx установить не получается. Что делать? Можно ли как-то сменить разрешение в nomodeset?

Comment: почитайте ветку [ссылка](http://www.linux.org.ru/news/ubuntu/12420747) у кого-то работает, у кого-то - нет(

Comment: и вместо nomodeset попробуй передать параметр video=1920x1280 (укажи нужное)